# When searching in a 2d matrix, its splitting string into its characters for some reason

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 2d matrix that i created using the code below. I have some code that fills it in with data that im using

```
matrix = [] #ClientID to Folder Name mapping
matrix.append([]) #Folder Name
matrix.append([]) #ClientID
```

When i do print(matrix[1]) , the output is, ['100108', '50004-A', '50004-B', '100114']

In the code below here, I'm trying to see if i exists in index 1 of my matrix. The output I'm getting from the is all coming from the else statement and is breaking down the 4 values in matrix[1] into their individual characters so there are no matches. How would i have the if statement search for i in matrix[1] for the full value not their pieces.

```
for i in clientInventory:
    if i in matrix[1]:
        print('good')
    else:
        print('Missing Client Performance folder: ' + str(i))
```

Here's an example of the output:

```
Missing Client Performance folder: [
Missing Client Performance folder: 1
Missing Client Performance folder: 0
Missing Client Performance folder: 0
Missing Client Performance folder: 1
Missing Client Performance folder: 0
Missing Client Performance folder: 8
Missing Client Performance folder: ,
```

Comment: What is clientInvetory ? It looks like it is a string since iterating it returns one character at a time.

Comment: @BenjaminRio clientInventory is the same as those 4 clientID that print out correctly when just doing print(matrix[1])

Comment: This is weird. What do you get when print(i) in client Invetory.

Comment: It looks like `clientInventory` is a string whose first 8 characters are "[100108,". Can you print `clientInventory`? Can you also print `matrix[1]`? This will be informative.